# Using spring batch config how to send a mail and how to configure in the job

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-jms

I need to send a mail using spring batch configs.in the mail having the status of the mail(It's success or failure) now am able to read data from csv and write into the Database.after write into the database i need to send a mail.
please any one suggest to me
this is my java config file job configuration

```
return jobs.get("insertIntoDbFromCsvJob")
            .start(readRegistrations())
                .build();
    }
```

here is am readRegistrations() step is read data from csv and write into the database.
now i need to send a mail if that step is succec or failure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908850/email-sending-in-spring-batch

Answer (score 5):

You can use spring email support and job listeners.

```
    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender javaMailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSenderImpl = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        javaMailSenderImpl.setHost("localhost");
        javaMailSenderImpl.setUsername("");
        javaMailSenderImpl.setPassword("");
        javaMailSenderImpl.setProtocol("smtp");
        javaMailSenderImpl.setPort(25);
        return javaMailSenderImpl;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMailMessage templateMessage() {
        SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
        mailMessage.setTo("to@gmail.com");
        mailMessage.setSubject("Job Status");
        mailMessage.setFrom("test@test.com");
        return mailMessage;
    }
```

***Implement a listener***

```
@Component
public class JobCompletionNotificationListener extends
        JobExecutionListenerSupport {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(JobCompletionNotificationListener.class);

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Autowired
    private SimpleMailMessage templateMessage;

    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        if (jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED) {
            log.info("!!! JOB FINISHED! Time to verify the results");
            SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage(
                    templateMessage);
            mailMessage.setText("Job Success");
            javaMailSender.send(mailMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

***Job Config***

```
@Autowired
private JobCompletionNotificationListener listener;

@Bean
public Job importUserJob(JobBuilderFactory jobs, Step s1,
        JobExecutionListener listener) {
    return jobs.get("importUserJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(listener).flow(s1).end().build();
}
```

Comment: where did you give the "JobCompletionNotificationListener" class name in job config

Comment: In your joblistener class name  is JobCompletionNotificationListener where did you configure in your job config

Comment: Just configure it as a spring bean and autowire it. I changed the config code now. Hope it is clear to you.

Comment: Please add mail.jar to your classpath .

Comment: It will be easier if you can google and find out. There are lots of examples available

Comment: how to configure the scheduling in job configuration .